# Fetch data from multiple columns within the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a searching feature on my website which searches and displays data!

My db structure is fairly simple. I have a table in which there are multiple columns but I want to fetch data on the basis of two columns, now I have a query that takes the user search as a parameter. What I want to do, is to search in two specific columns and return the data!

Here is my query:

```
$key=$_GET['key'];
$key=str_replace("-"," ",$key);
$query="
select rand_id
     , title_short
     , color
     , path
     , category
from data
where title_full LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')
";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
```

This query is fetching data from one column `title_full`, but what I want to do is to add another column here named `size` so that it searches from both columns.

Any help?

Comment: `and` operator may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done it myself i just added an OR condition at the end

```
$key=$_GET['key'];
                $key=str_replace("-"," ",$key);
                $query="select `rand_id`,`title_short`,`color`,`path`,`category` from `data` where `title_full` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') OR `size` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

                if($stmt){
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$key,$key);
                    $stmt->bind_result($rand_id,$title, $color, $path, $category);
                    $stmt->execute();
```